# Modulos vs Classes em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Estou começando a trabalhar com Classes em JavaScript. Mas vejo que algumas pessoas utilizam e recomendam a construção de um projeto separado por módulos. Como eu ainda não possuo experiência em trabalhar nesses formatos, gostaria de saber:

Quais são as vantagens de se trabalhar utilizando módulos e não classes no JavaScript?

Alguma das formas é melhor ou é apenas uma questão de escolha do programador?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Módulos e Classes são conceitos diferentes que não são necessariamente alternativos. Ou seja usar Classes não quer dizer que "então não se usa modulos" e vice versa.

**O que é um módulo?**

É possível através de ferramentas de desenvolvimento e/ou em ambiente Node.js (JavaScript versão servidor) criar módulos. Cada módulo é um ficheiro diferente onde todas as variáveis declaradas ficam restringidas ao escopo desse módulo. Ou seja nada é automaticamente exportado para o espaço global.

Isto é muito útil para criar componentes estanques e que podem facilmente ser modificados, usados noutros projetos e fáceis de ler/perceber o que fazem.

A única porta de contacto com o resto da aplicação é via `module.exports` em Node.js (nativo e muito usado), ou `export` em JavaScript do futuro que através das ditas ferramentas como Webpack, Babel, Browserify permitem já hoje usar essa sintaxe.

Quando se usam classes uma das vantagens é também reduzir o numero de variáveis que são exportadas para o escopo global. Esta boa ideia é talvez a única coisa em que módulos e classes têm em comum. De resto é muito comum ter classes declaradas dentro de módulos, uma ou mais.

Um exemplo de uma aplicação React.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Este módulo exporta uma Classe. E importa classes de outros módulos. A linha `import React, { Component } from 'react';` importa exatamente duas classes diferentes de um mesmo módulo. Ou seja esse módulo `react` é um objeto em que muitas das suas propriedades são Classes que podem ser importadas para outros módulos.

Comment: Valeu pelo esclarecimento! ;)

Comment: @Sergio sua resposta está correta, mas quando comparando Classes com Módulos, normalmente os livros falando de Modules Pattern que é diferente de Modules System (o que você apresentou na resposta). Mas a confusão é comum.

Comment: @GabrielGartz concordo que se pode falar de módulos no contexto de "modulos vs iife vs class". Na resposta abordei mais a questão de que modulos e classes podem coexistir e que não são polos alternativos. Vou dar uma edição mais logo e deixar mais claro. Bom reparo, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Antes do ES6 introduzir a sintaxe para classes no JavaScript, havia uma grande discussão de qual seria a melhor maneira para simular esse comportamento de linguagens orientada a objetos em JavaScript que é uma linguagem que apesar de ter objetos, usa prototipação e não classes.

`Modules pattern` que provavelmente é o que você está comparando a classes, é uma forma de iniciar um escopo, para que você possa ter variáveis apenas acessíveis dentro deste escopo e acessar elas pelos métodos da sua instância.

Nos dias de hoje é possível usar a sintaxe de `class` no ES6, caso a plataforma que você esteja usando não suporte você, pode usar projetos que transpilam seu código como o Babel, para dar suporte a este novo recurso do JavaScript. Por baixo dos panos a `class` vai criar algo similar ao modules pattern para te dar recursos similares a lingaugens que não fazem uso de protótipos.

Sabendo disso, é escolha do desenvolvedor optar pelo que será compatível com o projeto, ou melhor dará os recursos que se deseja utilizar para o tal.

Comment: Valeu pela dica! ;)